# List index out of range Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

hemos realizado este metodo pero tenemos un problema ya que el indice de la lista está fuera de rango.

Los valores de la variable son:

```
largo = 16 #La longitud del material genetico de cada individuo
num = 22 #La cantidad de individuos que habra en la poblacion
indAReproducir = 7 #Individuos elegidos para la reproduccion
probabilidadMutacion = 0.2 #La probabilidad de que un individuo mute

def mutation(poblacionNueva):
    """
    Se mutan los individuos al azar. Sin la mutacion de nuevos genes nunca podria
    alcanzarse la solucion.
    """
    #MUTACION UNIFORME

    for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
        if random.random() <= probabilidadMutacion: #Cada individuo de la poblacion (menos los padres) tienen una probabilidad de mutar
            punto = random.randint(0,largo-1)
            nuevo_valor = random.randint(1,9)

            while nuevo_valor == poblacionNueva[i][punto]:
                nuevo_valor = random.randint(1,9)

            poblacionNueva[i][punto] = nuevo_valor

    return poblacionNueva
```

EDIT:

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacionNueva):

    #Puntua todos los elementos de la poblacion (poblacionNueva) y se queda con los mejores
    #guardandolos dentro de 'selected'.
    #Despues mezcla el material genetico de los elegidos para crear nuevos individuos y
    #llenar la poblacion (guardando tambien una copia de los individuos seleccionados sin
    #modificar).

    #Por ultimo muta a los individuos.


    puntuados = [[calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva]

    def takeSecond(puntuados):
        return puntuados[1]

    puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) 
    poblacionNueva = puntuados

    selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-indAReproducir):] 

    for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
        punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) 
        padre = random.sample(selected, 2)
        poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = padre[0][:punto] 
        poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = padre[1][punto:] 

    return poblacionNueva
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a mutación, ¿qué valor le pasas como mutacionNueva? ¿Es un diccionario o una matriz? ¿Qué dimensión tiene esa matriz en caso de ser tal?

Comment: Es una lista y tiene 22 como dimensión

Comment: ¿Es una lista de listas donde la primera dimensión es `num` y la segunda es `largo`?

Comment: ¿Es posible que `poblacionNueva[i]` contenga una lista en la cual sus elementos sean menor que  `largo` (que es 16)?

Comment: Si, num vale 22 y cada array es de 16(largo)

Comment: Para poder precisar donde está el error deberias agregar un ejemplo real lo más pequeño posible de `poblacionNueva`. El error puede estar en `poblacionNueva[i][punto]` donde `punto` puede ser cualquier valor entre 0 y 15 (ambos incluidos). Debes asegurate que el iterable dentro de `poblacionNueva` tiene al menos 16 elementos.

Comment: ¿Y los hijos que no se destinan a la reproducción y pueden mutar, pueden ser cualquiera de la lista o solo los primeros?

Comment: No, cada elemento debe tener como longitud num ya que son numeros de 16 cifras @César

Comment: Me refiero a la población total. Es decir, hay parte de la población total (los que no se reproducen) que tienen la disposición a ser mutados. ¿Esos N que pueden ser mutados son los primeros N de la población total?

Comment: Mutados solo pueden ser los hijos que han salido de la reproducción de sus padres.

Comment: En el código dices que cada individuo de la población, menos los padres, puede ser mutado. Y supongo que el número de padres es `indAReproducir`, por eso haces el bucle un número de veces dado por `len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir`. De esta manera, el número de individuos con posibilidad de ser mutados son todos los de la población menos `indAReproducir`. Es decir, todos menos los padres, ¿no?

Comment: Si, correcto. Se pueden mutar todos los individuos de la población salvo los padres.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de población que le estás pasando a `mutation`?

Comment: Coincido con Carlos A. tal y como expresé más arriba sería mucho más simple si pudieras aportar un ejemplo real que **reproduzca** el problema del parámetro `poblacionNueva` pasado a `mutation`. Incluso la línea y la **traza conpleta** del error ayudarían mucho a delimitar el error. Saludos.

Comment: Sería una población de 22 numeros de 16 cifras cada una. Por ejemplo [5,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,1,3,5,6,2,8,7,9],[2,5,4,7,9,6,6,5,4,2,2,1,3,4,4,8],.....Asi hasta llegar a 22 numeros.

Comment: @CarlosLozano ¿Te sirvió la solución que te propuse en la respuesta?

Comment: Hemos probado tu método y es muy correcto pero al probar nuestra matriz nos ha salido el mismo error de antes " List index out of range". ¿ Puede ser que el método que voy a poner ahora nos esté dando mal la matriz?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez .

Comment: @CarlosLozano Vuestra función devuelve una matriz (lista de listas) donde hay listas que forman parte de dicha matriz que no tienen `largo` elementos (sólo tienen dos elementos). Por eso luego al usarla en mi función da error. La verdad es que no entiendo muy bien qué hacéis en vuestra función al obtener una población inicial.

Comment: Lo que estamos intentando hacer es generamos una poblacion al azar de 22 números(num) de 16 cifras cada uno. Luego, tenemos un metodo fitness que va comparando cada número con unas pistas( 22 numeros de 16 cifras) y obtenemos el valor fitness de cada numero. Cogemos los que mas fitness tengan ( indAReproducir) y vamos haciendo mutacion/reproduccion

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez .

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez ¿A que te refieres con 2 elementos?. Todas las listas de nuestra población inicial tienen 16 elementos o eso creemos

Comment: @CarlosLozano Esto `[[calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva]` genera lista de listas de 2 elementos. Suponiendo que `calcularFitness(i)` devuelva un número.

Comment: Si si, no hemos entendido la pregunta antes. @CarlosA.Gómez

Comment: @CarlosLozano Entonces esa lista está formada por listas de 2 elementos, y es el origen del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, has definido una función `mutation()` al cual le pasas una población que será mutada. La mutación de esta población se producirá solo a los elementos de ésta que no se van a reproducir y, entre estos, sólo se producirá la mutación en uno de sus genes (elegido de manera aleatoria) en caso de que cumpla cierta probabilidad.

En función de esto que te he descrito, voy a proponerte una solución explicando qué creo que falla en tu programa.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                           
#coding=utf-8                                                                    

import random                                                                    


def obtener_indices_mutables(tam_poblacion, tam_mutables):                       
    """                                                                          
    Obtener la lista de índices de los individuos de la población de un          
    tamaño determinado que podrán ser mutados.                                   

    Argumentos:                                                                  
        tam_poblacion: tamaño total de la población cuya parte podrá ser mutada. 
        tam_mutables: tamaño de parte de la población que podrá ser mutada.      

    Retorno:                                                                     
        Lista de índices de los individuos que podrán mutar. Esta lista tiene    
        un tamaño de tam_mutantes.                                               
    """                      
    return random.sample(range(tam_poblacion), tam_mutables))                                                    


def mutacion(poblacion, tam_reproductores, prob_mutacion, tam_genes):            
    """                                                                          
    Se mutan los individuos al azar. Sin la mutación de nuevos genes nunca       
    podría alcanzarse la solución.                                               

    Argumentos:                                                                  
        poblacion: población a mutar los individuos que no se reproducen. Lista  
            de listas donde cada elemento (individuo) de la lista principal          
            contiene una lista con los valores por cada gen.                         
        tam_reproductores: número de individuos de la población que se
            reproducirán. Es decir, los padres.                                      
        prob_mutacion: probabilidad de que un individo con posibilidad de ser    
            mutado, mute.                                                            
        tam_genes: longitud del material genético de cada individuo.             

    Retorno:                                                                     
        Población con los individuos mutados.                                    
    """                                                                          
    #MUTACION UNIFORME                                                           

    tam_poblacion = len(poblacion)                                               
    tam_mutables = tam_poblacion - tam_reproductores                             

    for i in obtener_indices_mutables(tam_poblacion, tam_mutables):                                                   
        if random.random() > prob_mutacion:                                      
            continue                                                             

        punto = random.randint(0, tam_genes-1)                                     
        valor = random.randint(1, 9-1)                                             
        poblacion[i][punto] = valor if valor < poblacion[i][punto] else valor+1                                                                                     

    return poblacion                                                             


def main():                                                                      
    """                                                                          
    Función principal.
    """                                                                          
    largo = 16 #La longitud del material genetico de cada individuo              
    num = 22 #La cantidad de individuos que habra en la poblacion                
    indAReproducir = 7 #Individuos elegidos para la reproduccion                 
    prob_mutacion = 0.2 #La probabilidad de que un individuo mute                

    poblacion = [[1]*largo for i in range(num)]                                  
    print(poblacion, "\n")                                                       

    poblacion = mutacion(poblacion, indAReproducir, prob_mutacion, largo)        
    print(poblacion)                                                             


if __name__ in ("__main__", "__console__"):                                      
    main()
```

En primer lugar, tenemos que el número de individuos que serán mutados son *N = población - padres*. A partir de esto, tal como lo tienes implementado, los elementos que serán mutados siempre serán los N primeros de la población. He de suponer que pueden ser N individuos cualesquiera de la población, por lo tanto ahí tienes el primer error.

Para solucionarlo, he implementado una función que te devuelve una lista de *N* elementos con índices aleatorios entre *0* y *población-1*.

**Actualización 2:** He modificado la manera de obtener un nuevo valor para la mutación eliminando el bucle y el uso de listas. De esta manera no tienes que ir probando valores aleatorios hasta que uno sea distinto del que ya existe en el gen. Con la modificación, directamente obtiene un valor distinto y lo guarda.

El resto es prácticamente igual a tu código con ligeras modificaciones. Lo he probado con una matriz de `num` filas y, por cada fila, `largo` elementos (con valores inicializados todos a 1), siendo esta matriz una posible población que le pasas a la función `mutacion()`. Lo he ejecutado y da ningún error de acceso a índices (al menos las pruebas que he hecho). Por lo tanto, quizás el error estaba en cómo tenías definida tu matriz de población.

**Actualización 3**: Optimizar la función `obtener_indices_mutables`.